# Deleted the meta keywords tag in head.phtml - but still showing up

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I deleted the meta keyword tag from the head.phtml in both the

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml
```

**AND**

```
app/design/frontend//default/template/page/html/head.phtml
```

Yet it still shows up on the products page? I want to get rid of the keyword tags on every product. I have deleted the cache both in the back end and manually yet it still shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is residing in your theme?

Which theme are you using?

Go to `frontend/your_theme/template/page/html/head.phtml` and remove it from there.

If none of these work, then you can enable template path hint and findout which phtml file is responsible for this.

[Check this for how to enable template path hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint)

Magento uses fall back method. What I mean by that is it always pools the template file from the active template, if not found then goes to `default` and again if not found then goes to `base` template.

Comment: The template path was in a folder different to expected so the path hint helped alot, thanks heaps!